# How to remove the other figure matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, subplot

i am new to this, can anybody tell how to remove the other figure?My code is as follows:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 2, sharey=True)
fig.set_size_inches(20, 10)

# use the same set of colors as above to compare side to side of the two graphs
colors = ['blue', 'green', 'red', 'purple', 'orange']
for e in set(kmeans.labels_):
    mark = kmeans.labels_ == e
    axes[0].scatter(feature_pca[:, 0][mark], feature_pca[:, 1][mark], color=colors[e], label=e, alpha=0.9)
axes[0].legend()
```

P.S- if i am making any change to   fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 2, sharey=True), i am getting error : TypeError: 'AxesSubplot' object is not subscriptable

[image]

Answer (score 1):

With

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 2, sharey=True)
```

you create a window with a grid of 1x2 subplots (so two in total). This means you get an array of with 2 axes.

Now to remove the second subplot you'd have to use

```
    fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 1, sharey=True)
```

In this case you get only *one* axes object, not an array. So to make that work you will have to replace `axes[0]` with just `axes`.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the help @flawr, i understood where i was going wrong. :)